# Easy way to implement large batch of files to HTML or PHP

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have 300 photos, and I want to add all 300 photos to my website. A simple HTML/CSS site.

I would then need to manual write every single tag and path by my self.

Isn't there a way to auto generate every line? Assuming my filenames are: image-01.png, image-02.png etc.

So indstead of writing all the way up to image-300.png, there could be a script, website or something else there could automatically generate all those tags from 01 to 300.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: make a loop for that

Comment: Use loops. from 1 to 300.

Comment: It makes sense but the question is too broad. You need to show us better what type of layout you want and what the HTML is to produce that. I can understand you don't have a clue how to code the PHP, but you need to show us the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for show 1 to 300 images.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=300;$i++)
{
    echo '<img src="image-'.$i.'.png" />';
}
?>
```